# How can I apply paper covering to a glossy ceiling?

Tags: drywall, ceiling

Ours is a 1911 SD house. We have a bedroom measuring 4.1M x 4.3M. We are about to redecorate the room. The ceiling (original plaster and lathe) finish is not the best and was formally gloss painted over to seal the flaking surface.

I was going to use Erfurt Wallrock Fibreliner paper with Wallrock power adhesive. However I'm told by the manufacture that the gloss would have to " be scraped off first".

If that is the case it would be easier to overboard and skim, any experience, ideas or knowledge of gloss finish ceilings?

Comment: What's an SD house? Do you mean that it's located in South Dakota or San Diego?

Comment: Wallpaper on a ceiling is a recipe for rage (and divorce in some cases). Ask me how I know.